# Minification for ES6 code in webpack using babel

Tags: webpack, babeljs, production-environment, bundling-and-minification

I have tried options such as Uglifyjs,babelli (babel-minify ).nothing seems to be working.Uglify throws some error like this:

Name expected [au680.bundle.js:147541,22]

babelli does not minifies the code either.Can any one give simple example of es6 minification making use of webpack 2, babel.
May be a plugin that do the work cleanly.

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var AppCachePlugin = require('appcache-webpack-plugin');

var appConfig= require('./config.js');
console.log("appConfig is ->>>",appConfig);
var appPort = appConfig.APP_PORT;//Port on which the application is running

process.noDeprecation = true;
var ASSET_PATH = '/'
module.exports = function(options) {
  var entry, jsLoaders, plugins, cssLoaders, devtool;
  console.log('options webconfig-->', options, 'directory name', __dirname);

  // If production is true
  if (options.prod) {
    console.log('production minification');
    // Entry
    entry = {
       veris:path.resolve(__dirname,'./VerisInstrument/js/VerisApp.js'),
       au680 : path.resolve(__dirname,'./Au680Instrument/js/au680App.js'),
    commondashboard:path.resolve(__dirname,'./CommonDashboard/js/CommonDashboardApp.js'),
       groups:path.resolve(__dirname,'./Groups/js/GroupsApp.js'),
       homepage : path.resolve(__dirname,'./HomePage/js/HomePageApp.js'),
       infohealthcheck : path.resolve(__dirname,'./Common/js/infohealthcheckapp.js')
      
    };

   
    // Plugins
    plugins = [// Plugins for Webpack
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }
   }),
  //   new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true,comments : false,compress: {
  //   // remove warnings
  //   warnings: false,

  //   // Drop console statements
  //   drop_console: true
  // }})

    
      // new es3MemberExpressionLiterals(),
      //
      
    ];

  // If app is in development
  } else {
    devtool = 'source-map';
    // Entry
    // entry = [
    //   "webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:" + appPort, // Needed for hot reloading
    //   "webpack/hot/only-dev-server", // See above
    //   //path.resolve(__dirname,'./app') // Start with js/app.js...
    //   path.resolve(__dirname,'./VerisInstrument/js/VerisApp')
    // ];
  //   require("babel-core").transform("code", {
  //   plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
  // });
    entry = {
      main: [
        "webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:" + appPort, // Needed for hot reloading
        "webpack/hot/only-dev-server" // See above
      ],
      //path.resolve(__dirname,'./js/app') // Start with js/app.js...
     veris : path.resolve(__dirname,'./VerisInstrument/js/VerisApp'),
      au680 : path.resolve(__dirname,'./Au680Instrument/js/au680App.js'),
   commondashboard:path.resolve(__dirname,'./CommonDashboard/js/CommonDashboardApp.js'),
      groups:path.resolve(__dirname,'./Groups/js/GroupsApp.js'),
      homepage : path.resolve(__dirname,'./HomePage/js/HomePageApp.js'),
      infohealthcheck : path.resolve(__dirname,'./Common/js/infohealthcheckapp.js')
      
    };
    
    // Only plugin is the hot module replacement plugin
    plugins = [
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      }
     }),
     new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()// Make hot loading work,
    ]
  }

  return {
    devtool: devtool,
    entry: entry,
    // output: { // Compile into js/build.js
    //   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    //   filename: "js/bundle.js",
    //   publicPath : '/'
    // },
    output: { // Compile into js/build.js
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      publicPath : ASSET_PATH
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
      {
          test: /\.js$/, // Transform all .js files required somewhere within an entry point...
          loader: 'babel-loader', // ...with the specified loaders...
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          options: {
          presets: ['es2015','react','stage-2','env'],
          plugins: [require('babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread'),require('babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring'),require('babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters')]
        }
          // query : {
          //   presets : ['es2015','react','stage-2','env']
          // }

        }
        , {
          test:   /\.css$/, // Transform all .css files required somewhere within an entry point...
          use : [
            {
              loader : 'style-loader'
            },
            {
              loader : 'css-loader'
            },
            {
              loader : 'postcss-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
          ] // ...with PostCSS
        }, {
          test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/i,
          loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
        },
        { test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
         loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
      ]
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    target: "web", // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
    stats: false, // Don't show stats in the console
    node: {
      fs: "empty"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `UglifyJsPlugin`? Have you made sure your code has no errors?

Comment: Following error comes in when trying to use UglifyJsPlugin

ERROR in au680.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Name expected [au680.bundle.js:147540,22]
webpack: Failed to compile.

Comment: Application runs but i cannot see any minification happening and also seeing error in CLI

Answer (score 14):

### Update

If you aren't worried about supporting older browsers, [webpack v4+ will minify your code by default in production mode](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#minification):

```
webpack --mode=production
```

### Previous answer

From https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2545:

> The problem is that UglifyJS doesn't support ES6 yet so it's not possible to avoid that transformation yet. You can follow the progress at [mishoo/UglifyJS2#448](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/448) .

There are many solutions; here are a couple:

**Transpile your ES6 code first, then minify it**
For maximum compatibility, transpile using Babel and then minify with Babel Minify (formerly Babili):

1. Install [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) and [babel-minify-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/babel-minify-webpack-plugin)

   ```
   npm install babel-loader babel-minify-webpack-plugin --save-dev
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   yarn add babel-loader babel-minify-webpack-plugin --dev
   ```
2. Add this to webpack.config.js:

   ```js
   const MinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');

   module.exports = {
     // ...
     module: {
       rules: [
         {
           test: /\.js$/,
           use: {
             loader: 'babel-loader',
             options: {
               presets: ['env']
             }
           }
         }
       ]
     },
     plugins: [
       new MinifyPlugin()
     ]
   };
   ```

   Or if you prefer you can use UglifyJS instead of Babel Minify:

   ```js
   const MinifyPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
   ```

**Minify your ES6 code without transpiling**
For compatibility only with browsers that support the ES6 features you're using, minify using Babel Minify without transpiling:

1. Install [babel-minify-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/babel-minify-webpack-plugin)

   ```
   npm install babel-minify-webpack-plugin --save-dev
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   yarn add babel-minify-webpack-plugin --dev
   ```
2. Add this to webpack.config.js:

   ```js
   const MinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');

   module.exports = {
     // ...
     plugins: [
       new MinifyPlugin()
     ]
   };
   ```

The default settings for Babel Minify worked fine for me but you can see here for more options you can customize: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/babel-minify-webpack-plugin

Comment: So for the second method, "Minify your ES6 code without transpiling", do you know how to put existing babel options into it? like transform class properties, spread object, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Although I am creating a create-react-app like lib. So I have to pass in the Babel option object instead of relying .babelrc file.

Comment: @garyx Okay, I think I understand the question better now. The problem is the second method skips the transpiling process (which is what Babel does), so it doesn't make any sense to me to provide Babel options to it. If you want Babel to be run, I think the first method is what you need. You can, however, use babel-minify (Babili) with the first method. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score -3):

Following is my webpack configurations file. I am using webpack 2.3.1 with dynamic routing of react-router. Hope it helps you.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var package=require('./package.json');
var config = require('./config');
var ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');


const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var getPlugins = function(){
  var pluginsList = [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: Infinity,
      filename: 'vendor.bundle_[hash].js'
    }),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
         NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
       }
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'build-manifest.json'
    })
  ];
    pluginsList.push(new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: false
    }));
    pluginsList.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      output: {
        comments: false
      },
      sourceMap: false,
      minimize: true
    }));
  return pluginsList;
}



module.exports = {
  cache: true,
  output: {
    path:path.join(__dirname, "dist/js"),
    filename: "[name]_[hash].js",
    chunkFilename:"[name]_[hash].js",
    publicPath:config.envConfig.JS_ASSETS_PATH
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    port: 8080
  },

  entry: {
    index: [
      package.paths.app
    ],
    vendor: [
      'react', 'react-dom','phrontend',
      'react-ga'
    ]
  },
  plugins: getPlugins(),
  target: 'web',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
};
```