# Webpack's UglifyJsPlugin throws error with Node modules containing let

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js, uglifyjs2

This is the relevant code (I'm using Vue.js' [Webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) official template):

**.babelrc:**

```
"presets": [
  "babel-preset-es2015",
  "babel-preset-stage-2",
]
```

**webpack.prod.config.js**

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: {
    warnings: false,
    drop_console: shouldDropConsole
  },
  sourceMap: true
}),
```

This is the error I get when I do `npm run build`:

> ERROR in static/js/vendor.a6271913414e87e123c2.js from UglifyJs
>   Unexpected token: name (_months)
>   [./node_modules/calendar-js/index.js:56,0][static/js/vendor.a6271913414e87e123c2.js:90602,6]

This is the offending line:

```
let _months = MONTHS;
```

(If I replace all the `let`'s to `var`s the project is built without problems. And the `const`'s don't seem to bother Webpack/UglifyJS.)

Do I need to configure something so that Webpack/UglifyJS build node modules containing `let`'s? (The `let`'s in my actual project don't give me problems.)

Comment: ensure Babel plugin is executed BEFORE Uglify.

Comment: @skyboyer Could you illustrate how to do that in a Webpack project?

Comment: sorry, I was wrong: it should be `babel-loader` not `babel-plugin`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45222198/2071697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because you might be using an older version of `node` which does not support es6 syntax.

`let`, `const`, arrow functions etc. are part of es6 syntax. To know more follow this link http://es6-features.org/

You might need the older version of `node` for your other projects so install nvm. NVM is a node version manager which will help you to switch between node versions easily. Follow the link for documentation and installation process https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Node v6+ supports ES6 syntax try upgrading to that.

**UPDATE**

On the comments of this answer, it's confirmed that it was not a version issue and got resolved by following this GitHub issue thread https://github.com/joeeames/WebpackFundamentalsCourse/issues/3.

Peace!

Comment: I'm using v8.5.0.

Comment: hi @alex try looking on to this thread https://github.com/joeeames/WebpackFundamentalsCourse/issues/3

Comment: Using the new standalone UglifyJS plugin fixed the problem ... maybe you can update your answer?